# How to read a <li> table in a webpage

Tags: html, r, xml, xpath

I debug the program many times to get the result as follows:

```
url                  研究所知识库列表
/handle/1471x/1      力学研究所
/handle/1471x/8865   半导体研究所
```

However, no metter what parameters I use, the result is not correct. The content in this table is one part of the basis of my further analysis, and I am very trembled for it. I'm looking forward to your help with great sincerity.

```
    ## download community-list ---the 1st level of IR Grid
        #loading webpage and analyzing
        community_url<-"http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/community-list"
        com_source <- readLines(community_url, encoding = "UTF-8")
        com_parsed <- htmlTreeParse(com_source, encoding = "UTF-8", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
        # get table specs
        tableNodes <- getNodeSet(com_parsed, "//table")
        com_tb<-readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[8]], header=TRUE)
        # get External links
        xpath <- "//a/@href"
        getHTMLExternalFiles(tableNodes[[8]], xpQuery = xpath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is unclear exactly what you want your end result to look like but if you modify your xpath statements a bit to take advantage of the DOM structure you can get something like this:

```
library(XML)
community_url<-"http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/community-list"
com_source <- readLines(community_url, encoding = "UTF-8")
com_parsed <- htmlTreeParse(com_source, encoding = "UTF-8", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
list_header <- xpathSApply(com_parsed, '//table[.//li]//h1', xmlValue)
hrefs <- xpathSApply(com_parsed, '//li[@class="communityLink"]//@href', function(x) unname(x))
display_text <- xpathSApply(com_parsed, '//li[@class="communityLink"]//a', xmlValue)
table_data <- cbind(display_text, hrefs)
colnames(table_data) <- c(list_header, "url")
table_data
```

console output causes stackoverflow to think this answer is spam but here is a screen shot: [image]

Comment: `list_header <- xpathSApply(com_parsed, '//table[.//li]//h1', xmlValue)`

Comment: `list_header <- xpathSApply(com_parsed, '//table[.//li]//h1', xmlValue)` I could not image that we must use '//table[.//li]' to get the exact location of this table, because the table have two levels, the first level only include //h1, the second level contain //li, If the table have more than 2 levels, we can still use '//table[.//li]' to select whole table, even the content out of //li marks?

Comment: yes, //table[.//li] will select each table that contains at least one child <li> element and it will return the table and all sub-elements... you can learn more about xpath [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)